# how to populate second date field when user select the first one with Datepicker plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to auto fill the second date field with 7 days added to the first date that user selects from the datpicker for the datefield provided with jquery. I tried this code  but it is adding a month even though I want it to add 7 days.

```
$("#to").datepicker();
    $("#from").datepicker({
        onSelect:function(){
            var date=$(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#to").datepicker("setDate",new Date(date.getTime()));
            $("#to").datepicker("setDate", "+7d");
        }
});
```

Comment: `+7d` is counted from the user's time, not the time that's currently shown in the datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#to").datepicker();
    $("#from").datepicker({
        onSelect:function(){
            var date=$(this).datepicker('getDate');
            date.setDate(date.getDate()+7); // Add 7 days to the selected day
            $("#to").datepicker("setDate", date);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
$("#from").datepicker();
$("#to").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        var toDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+7)
        $("#from").datepicker("setDate", toDate);
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fgKm7/)**

In your question you said you want to add seven days to the date the user selects which I assume would be the from date, not the to date, as your code would indicate.